# Django TypeError: render() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am sending an email to my drivers from my employee site but I am not able to send a driver id with the url link. I get the error:

```
join_message = template.render(ctx, request)**
TypeError: render() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given**
```

My view:

```
def rentacar_carapp_approve(request):
    if request.POST:
        try:
            args['driver'] = driver = Driver.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('driver_id'))
            subject = "Please Register Your Car"
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            to_email = 'bakrshk@gmail.com'
            if to_email is not None:
                template = Template("""Please hit the link and book a car {{ request.get_host }}{% url 'detail' driver_id=driver_id %}""")
                ctx = Context({'driver_id': driver.id})
                join_message = template.render(ctx, request)
                send_mail(subject=subject, from_email=from_email, recipient_list=[to_email], message=join_message,
                          fail_silently=False)
                print("email sent")
        except Driver.DoesNotExist:
            print("Driver doesn't exists")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/mega-admin/rentacar/carapp-manager/')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass the `request` to the template context you can either explicitly include it in the context:

```
template = Template("""Please hit the link and book a car {{ request.get_host }}{% url 'detail' driver_id=driver_id %}""")
ctx = Context({'driver_id': driver.id, 'request': request})
join_message = template.render(ctx, request)
```

Or you can use `RequestContext` (assuming you have the request context processor enabled.

```
template = Template("""Please hit the link and book a car {{ request.get_host }}{% url 'detail' driver_id=driver_id %}""")
ctx = RequestContext(request, {'driver_id': driver.id})
join_message = template.render(ctx, request)
```

Note that it's unusual to instantiate templates from strings (e.g. `template = Template("""...""")`). Usually, you would save the template to a file in your templates directory (e.g. `car_approve.email`), then use the `render_to_string` shortcut to render the template. The `render_to_string` template *does* accept `request` as an argument.

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
context = {'driver_id': driver.id}
join_message = render_to_string('car_approve.email', context, request=request)
```

Comment: Thankyou for correcting my question and giving a wonderful answer. Alasdir do i have to create a template in my template directory or just i pass this .

Comment: The first two options are just changes to your code, they still use `template = Template("""...""")`. The third option requires you to create a file that contains `Please hit the link...` in your `templates` directory. It's up to you which option you choose, but the third option is best practice because it separates the template from the code.

Comment: Thankyou again . Alasdair can you send me the link or some example off third option how to do . make a file and Please hit the link .

Comment: Creating a template file is straight forward. It's [covered in the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something).

Comment: Thank you @ALasdair

Comment: Passing `request` to `template.render` method results in `TypeError: render() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given` in django 3.2. At least when `request` is created with `django.test.RequestFactory`, didn't test it with a real regular request object.

Answer (score 2):

You should not give the request parameter.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Template

To explain the error message, you are giving 2 arguments to the render method, which is bound to a template insance. This "function" actually receive 3 parameters, the first one being "self" (your Template instance).

Comment: so if i want to pass all three what should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

First, You need to remove `request` from `join_message = template.render(ctx, request)` and use `join_message = template.render(ctx)`

see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context)

then build it properly:

```
template = Template("""Please hit the link and book a car {{ booking_link }}""")
ctx = Context({'booking_link': request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('detail', kwargs={'driver_id': driver_id}))})
join_message = template.render(ctx)
```

[build_absolute_uri docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri)

[reverse docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/)

I did not test it, but it should return what you are looking for...

Comment: i removed the request its not sending the url path with it . Please hit the link and book a car /drivers/2/

Comment: updated my answer to use Django's built in tools to generate a url

Comment: but the url of my directory is not showing just /drivers/1/ is generate in email . driver id is correct but url path is not with it

Comment: sir how do i use as template \

Comment: I thought you already selected a correct answer? what is the issue?